# {culture} tag in route is not working for c# dotnet 7 minimal api

Tags: c#, culture, minimal-apis

For API project with controllers, {culture} tag can be used to set the culture for the called api. When used like this swagger GUI asks for the culture separately. But when I use the same approach with minimal api, {culture} tag is not being replaced with the culture (en-US / tr-TR / ...) but needs to be typed exactly as {culture}.

Expected behaviour

[image]

In other words I need to call the api as /{culture}/login instead of /en-US/login.

The problematic swagger design

[image]

This is the minimal api code which is not working.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
#region WeatherInfo
var summaries = new[]
{
    "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
};
app.MapGet("/{culture}/weatherforecast", () =>
{
    var forecast =  Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index =>
        new WeatherForecast
        (
            DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
            Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
        ))
        .ToArray();
    return forecast;
})
.WithName("GetWeatherForecast")
.WithOpenApi();
#endregion

app.Run();

record WeatherForecast(DateOnly Date, int TemperatureC, string? Summary)
{
    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define culture as a route parameter.

```
app.MapGet("{culture}/weatherforecast", (string culture) =>
{
    var forecast = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index =>
        new WeatherForecast
        (
            DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
            Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
        ))
        .ToArray();
    return forecast;
})
.WithName("GetWeatherForecast")
.WithOpenApi();
```

Then it'll show up in the UI.